# When i run the monkey runner, i am getting swt error

Tags: monkeyrunner

I have created the below script and saved it as (test.mr) in the lib folder and running from the command prompt C:\Android_Stuff\android-sdk-windows\tools\lib\monkeyrunner test.mr

```
@Importing monkeyrunner    
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

@waiting for the device connection
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

@Installing my app.
device.installPackage('C:/Android_Stuff/android-sdk-windows/tools/lib/purchase.apk')

@starting my demo page
device.startActivity(component='com.mobilemoneynetwork.purchase/.demo')

@selecting the Menu Button.
device.press('KEYCODE_MENU','DOWN_AND_UP')
```

I am getting

```
Unable to access jarfile ..\framework\archquery.jar
SWT folder '' does not exist.
Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
```

Comment: Now i am not getting the above error..Some how it is done the installation..Now i need to proceed the tapping my app...please suggest how to select the installed app through monkeyrunner..

Answer (score 2):

Set ANDROID_SWT path in environment variable it should be "your path"\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64